# sudo apt install build-essential error on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: cpp (= 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) but 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gcc : Depends: cpp (= 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) but 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9)
             Depends: libcrypt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to install packages that are not from the basic repositories. Please add the output of `apt policy build-essential` to your question and disclose any ppas that you have added to your system.

Comment: no happened only the output

sudo apt policy build-essential
build-essential:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 12.8ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     12.8ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     12.8ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @lakshman please [edit] that information into your question

Answer (score 2):

Per request you provided the output of `apt policy build-essential` as follows:

```
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 12.8ubuntu1.1 
Version table: 
    12.8ubuntu1.1 500 500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages 
    12.8ubuntu1 500 500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

The obvious problem here is that you are running 22.04 (jammy) and you are using 20.04 (focal) sources.

The proper output for this package in 22.04 looks like this

```
  Installed: 12.9ubuntu3
  Candidate: 12.9ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 12.9ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The fix is to correct `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Also please post a link about how to correct sources.list